# change listbox items behavior like radio button in expression blend

Tags: wpf, listbox, expression-blend, rectangles, contentpresenter

I have a `ListBox`.

I want to have a `ContentPresenter`, an `Image` and a `Rectangle` in every Item of the `ListBox`.

So I decided to create an Item template for `ListBox`.

Now, I have two Items in `ContentPresenter`.

1. Path of the image and
2. Color of the rectangle.

So I created a sample data source and I bind both path and color to image source and `Rectangle` fill respectively.

I have not directly binded the rectangle fill to the color(value) of the sample data source.
I have binded it in the rectangle's `LeftMouseButtonDown` event using `changePropertyAction` Behavior.

Now I can change the color of the rectangle when I click on the `Rectangle`.

But the problem is I also want to change the color of the other rectangles to its initial color while i click on any rectangle. I mean I want them to behave like radio buttons.

This is what I have :

[image]

This is what I want :

[image] [image]

Comment: You are not asking a question here. Anyway why are you not making a radio button template. Would this not be better as there is only one button active in a group

Comment: well if it's a `ListBox` why don't you just add a `Trigger` to the `ItemTemplate` to check if the `ListBoxItem` is Selected and apply your new color. You don't have to handle any special "Shared-Group" policies if it's already available to you via the ListBox. You can specify `SelectionMode="Single"` explicitly if you want to be sure only one item is selected at a time.

Comment: Well, nice tip from you. But I don't change the fill color of rectangle on the selection of the listItem. I mean I change the fill color on the leftMouseButtonDown on Image. And also I have specified `SelectionMode = "Single"`.

Comment: Sorry, for the above comment. I misunderstood your answer. Yes, I can add a `trigger` as you say, that will give me rights to tell something to `storyboard`. I mean I can control the storyboard using `IsSelected` Property. But what happens here is that the background color of `selected rectangle` is `not same` for `all the rectangles`. I mean I have to take the color of selection of a specific rectangle from the `sample data source`. So I use `ChangePropertyAction Behavior`. At this point I am unable to check IsSelected for the specific listItem. Now, `Can you point me to the right direction?`